# FontColor Icon change based on selection

Tags: c#, icons

My question is pretty simple: How can I change the icon based on the color selection?

Say I start with an A underlined with red. If I select Blue from the colorpicker, how do I get that blue under my A?

Thanks
Team JoKi

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET? XNA?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joe White, I'm sorry I failed to provide more info. Luckely Cody Gray was able to point me in the right direction :)

Comment: It would still be helpful if you told us which UI framework you're using. Don't forget, this question and answer are here for other people to use as a reference in the future. By not specifying what your question *is,* you're doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is surprisingly lacking in necessary details, so I'm going to try and see if I can fill in some of the blanks...

I assume that by "the icon", you mean one that you've found that looks similar to the one used in Microsoft Word:  [image]   And I assume that you've placed that icon in some type of toolbar. And I further assume that, upon clicking the icon (or the drop-down arrow next to the icon) in the toolbar, the user is presented with a color-picker control, from which they can select a custom color.

So your question is, how can I change that default red underline to match the color that the user has selected in my color picker control.

The short answer is that you can't. If you pay close attention, most applications *don't* update the color of this icon in accordance with the chosen color. It's way more work than it's worth, considering that it will add little value to your application once complete. Surprisingly few users will even *notice* this "feature".

But if you want to do this, you'll need to create and modify an icon on-the-fly, after the user has chosen a color. Start with a template icon, one without any color filled in for the color rectangle at all. You can create this from your existing icon using an icon editor application (like my personal favorite, [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/)).

Once you've created your template icon, you need to write code that loads this icon into a bitmap ([`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)), fills the appropriate rectangular region with the selected color ([`Graphics.FillRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangle.aspx)), and then converts that bitmap back into an icon. Finally, assign the icon you've created in memory to the toolbar button, and marvel what what you've accomplished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cody. Sorry for the lack of information (I figured my question was clear enough, but you're right I should have provided you with more info), but all your assumptions were right ;) I'm also going to listen to your advice, and I'm going to leave it the way it is, it was just a small feature anyway. Thanks for the answer, it was just what I needed!

Comment: @Team: That's good to hear. Sometimes, I wonder if my answers are discouraging. People have good ideas about little features to implement, but I've tried to do most of these things myself already. And it turns out that they're just not worth it. I think passing that information on is what's most valuable. I would have loved to received confirmation from 'experts' that what I was about to try to do was simply more effort than it was worth and I should strongly consider giving up! Anyway, as is the case with these things, it *is* possible should you decide you want to pursue it eventually.